# Webgrid ajax call MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

The goal:

To populate the webgrid when selecting the next page via ajax (I do not want the page to reload).

Currently I have :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = (from a in _context.Audit
                 select new
                 {
                     a.AuditId,
                     a.FirstInserted,
                     a.FirstInsertedBy,
                     a.IsDeleted
                 }).ToList();
    return View(users);
}
```

and

```
@{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
}
<div id="grid">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>")
</div>
```

The problem:

The webgrid shows up but it seems to only do a get call on the index action. How can I change this so that it will preform an ajax call to a method supplying the model?

I have looked here and it did not give me too much of a hint to accomplish this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Comment: will you post the entire code how you achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, apparently you have to add jquery to the head of the page and it works.